# cx_Oracle queries: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, jupyter-notebook, rdbms, cx-oracle

cur.execute("""
SELECT location, AVG(temp) as avg_temp
FROM (SELECT location,temp, ROWNUM rnum
FROM time_series_location_temp
ORDER BY avg_temp ASC)
WHERE rnum <= 6;
""")
I'm trying to execute this code but keep running into this error DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17344/3055250712.py in 
----> 1 cur.execute("""
2     SELECT LOCATION_ID, AVG(temp) as avg_temp
3     FROM (SELECT LOCATION_ID,temp
4           FROM time_series_location_temp
5           ORDER BY temp ASC)

DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

What's wrong and how should I re-write it?

I've tries to rewrite it and still the error comes up. I was expecting that the code would run and execute my query correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error almost invariably means that you have left the semicolon on the end of the statement. This is needed in SQL*Plus but needs to be removed when using cx_Oracle (or the new python-oracledb).